# Automatically open Office documents on a Sharepoint Server 2013 in Firefox (full Office integration)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I recently switched to Firefox. Unfortunately my company still uses Sharepoint Server 2013 (migration to Sharepoint Online is planned somewhere in the future) which no longer offers a fluid integration with Office.

Every time I want to edit an Office document, it gets downloaded instead of being 'forwarded' to be opened by Word, Excel, etc. Modifications need to be saved locally and than uploaded afterwards. This is hugely annoying.

Is there some way that I can automate this in code, using a Firefox extension? Does Sharepoint expose some kind of hook or metadata containing the document's URL?

Comment: This looks very helpful. However, we want material here to be presented in Q&A format. Would it be possible to turn this into an on-topic question? What was the problem you had before you discovered the answer?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(Self-answer originally provided by [Dotsoltecti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13365508/dotsoltecti); copied from question body into a proper answer).</sup>

Sharepoint 2013 passes the document's URL via the right-click contextual menu.

There exists a very neat add-on for Firefox called ["custom right-click menu"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-right-click-menu/) by Sander Ronde. After installing this extension I added the script below:

```
var feedback = crmAPI.getClickInfo();
var url = feedback.linkUrl;
if (url.endsWith("docx") || url.endsWith("doc")) { var uri = "ms-word:ofe|u|" }
if (url.endsWith("xlsx") || url.endsWith("xls")) { var uri = "ms-excel:ofe|u|" }
if (url.endsWith("pptx") || url.endsWith("ppt")) { var uri = "ms-powerpoint:ofe|u|"}
var toOpen = uri.concat(url);
window.open(toOpen);
```

*Et voilà*: right clicking on a Word/Excel/PowerPoint-document executes the script and correctly forwards the document to the said program (you have to whitelist your SharePoint-site with the pop-up blocker). Modifications are handled directly by the Office-program.

Only drawback so far is that every time a document is opened, a new blank window is generated. I haven't found a solution for that yet, so suggestions are always welcome.